# How to transfer Image between netbeans platform modules?

Tags: java, image, netbeans-platform

What is the best way to transfer images between netbeans platform modules? I thought about `BufferedImage`, or `InputStream` or as `byte[]`??
Now is the page on the disk and I use the `File` object to get the image, but i feel that this is not the right way.
In the future, there is a possibility that the image will be transfered to some server.
The image will be used to create the ocr in another module or on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard for loosely couple communication in the NetBeans platform is the [lookup](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansDeveloperFAQ#Lookup).
An option would be to pass around [FileObjects](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqFileObject) referring to the images.